# Error when concatenate square of a each digit of a number

Tags: c

I'm doing a Codewars Challenge. I must square every digit of a number and concatenate them.
So, if we run 9119 through the function, 811181 will come out, because 9<sup>2</sup> is 81 and 1<sup>2</sup> is 1.

My code is below:

```
#include <math.h>

unsigned long long square_digits (unsigned n)
{
  // Count for digits
  int digits = log10(n) + 1, i = 0;
  
  // Array to store the split number
  int numDivided[digits];
  
  // Store concatenated numbers
  unsigned long long result = 0;
  
  if (n == 0)
  {
    return result;
  }
  
  // Split number and store their square
  while (n > 0) 
  {
    numDivided[i] = pow(n % 10, 2);
    n /= 10;
    i++;
  }
  
  // Concatenated square of numbers
  for (i = digits - 1;i >= 0;i--)
  {
    if (numDivided[i] == 0)
    {
      result *= 10; 
    }
    else
    {
      // Count digits of the current number
      digits = log10(numDivided[i]) + 1;
    
      // Multiply current result for 10^(digits)
      result *= pow(10, digits);
      
      // Add the current number to result
      result += numDivided[i];
    }
  }
  
    return result;
}
```

The test cases are below:

```
Test(test_suite, sample_tests)
{
    do_test(      3212u,                9414ull);
    do_test(      2112u,                4114ull);
    do_test(         0u,                   0ull);
    do_test(       999u,              818181ull);
    do_test(     10001u,               10001ull);
    do_test(3210987654u,    9410816449362516ull);
    do_test(3999999999u, 9818181818181818181ull); // :p
    do_test(   UINT_MAX,  164811681364948125ull);
}
```

The code works until the two last tests, so:

```
for n = 3999999999, expected 9818181818181818181, but got 9818181818181818449
```

I was think that the test case was wrong and check if the number was greater that ULLONG_MAX but it's less, so, all right.

What is my mistake at this point?

Comment: What is `do_test`? What does it do? Might it be possible to create a proper [mre] to show us instead (with a simple `main` function that calls your function with a hard-coded argument and displays the result)? You might want to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Also, have you tried to use a *debugger* to step through your function, while monitoring variables and their values, to see what happens and when things start to go wrong?

Comment: Lastly, you do know that [`pow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow) is a floating point function, with all the possible problems that might entail?

Comment: `do_test` is the function provided for test the program. This takes an input how first argument and compare the expected output with the second argument.
So, for input 3212u is expected the output 9414ull, for example.

Comment: What problems could i have with pow function?
There is any alternative?

Comment: Simple multiplication of the number with itself? `numDivided[i] = (n % 10) * (n % 10)`?

Comment: Juan [For avoid the case of digit 0 i check at first if N == 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69370963/error-when-concatenate-square-of-a-each-digit-of-a-number/69375588#comment122612835_69371152) --> code does `digits = log10(n)` (bad) before `if (n == 0)` (too late).

Answer (score 2):

> [What problems could i have with pow function? There is any alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69370963/error-when-concatenate-square-of-a-each-digit-of-a-number/69375588#comment122612585_69370963)

`pow()` typically returns, at best, a 53 significant bit result yet we have at least a 64-bit problem. `powl()` does not certianly help either as it may be as limiting as `pow()`.  Do not use floating point functions for an integer problem. Using a floating point funtion for an integer problem is the wrong approach.

`digits = log10(n) + 1` are `numDivided[i] = pow(n % 10, 2)` are not specified to get the desired value (due to imprecision) and certainly fail when `n == 0`.

Simple extract the least significant decimal digit with `%10`.  Scale by an integer type power-of-10.

```
unsigned long long square_digits(unsigned n) {
  unsigned long long nn = 0;
  unsigned long long pow10 = 1;

  while (n) {
    unsigned digit = n % 10;
    unsigned square = digit * digit;  // 0 to 81
    nn += square * pow10;
    if (square < 10) {
      pow10 *= 10;
    } else {
      pow10 *= 100;
    }
    n /= 10;
  }
  return nn;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The main culprit is this line:

```c
result *= pow(10, digits);
```

Given that `result` is an `unsigned long long` while the return value of `pow` is a `double`, `result` is first converted to a `double`, then multiplied by the power and finally the result is converted back to an `unsigned long long`.

The problem is that while a `double` type has a much greater range than an `unsigned long long`, its precision is limited and not *all* the possible integral values can be represented (stored) exactly.

In particular, you can check the result of the following line:

```c
printf("%.0lf\n", 981818181818181ull * 100.0);  // It won't print 98181818181818100
```

See @[chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux-reinstate-monica)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69375588/4944425) for further details and a proper implementation of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found two mistakes in your code.

- `log()` is not defined for `0`. So, you cannot run your code against Test case 3.
- Use `powl()` instead of `pow()`.

PS: One change you can do to pass test case 3 is check if `N == 0` in the beginning of the function itself. The next script should calculate the number of digits in `N`.

Comment: For avoid the case of digit 0 i check at first if `N == 0` and return `result` that at this program point is 0 and so test case 3 works fine.
In the other cases i check if digit is 0 and, if it's true, it multiplies  the result by 10 (to adding digit 0 to result) and so avoid use the function `log10()`

Comment: I used `powl` instead of `pow` and everything works fine. Here's a reference for you.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow

Comment: `powl()` has the same trouble as `pow()` when `long double` and `double` have the [same encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/9cx8xs15(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).